# Is there a way to show Django messages in Django admin site?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-admin, django-messages, django-admin-tools

I need to display a Django message on the Django admin index site. I am looking for a way to add certain conditions for the message to be displayed and pass it to Django index site. Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: are you looking for description kind of message explaining how a field is to be created in admin panel  ??

Comment: I trying to show an alert message on the admin:index page when a certain condition is true.

Answer (score 0):

You should do this by customizing your django admin stie. In the `admin.py` module of your app you should define a new `AdminSite` and override the `index` method. In the `index` method you can add your custom messages:

```
# [<app>/admin.py]

from django.views.decorators.cache import never_cache
from django.contrib import admin

class CustomAdminSite(admin.AdminSite):
    @never_cache
    def index(self, request, extra_context=None):
        messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'This is a message.')
        return super().index(request, extra_context)
```

Then don't forget to change the default admins site to your `CustomAdminSite`:

```
# [<app>/admin.py]

admin_site = CustomAdminSite(name='myadmin')
```

Then in the project's `urls.py` use your custom `admin_site`:

```
# [<project>/urls.py]

from <app>.admin import admin_site

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('', admin_site.urls),
]
```